# Reading a specific field in IBM iSeries database environment with VBscript

Tags: vbscript, ibm-midrange

I am making a macro for my job which will update prices for specific items for specific purchase orders. Currently, I enter the information into an excel spreadsheet and then generate code through VBA which I paste into a text file and run through our IBM iSeries database environment. My code crashes trying to read the field in the environment and says:

> "Error in the script on line 41. Object doesn't support this property
>   or method: 'autECLSession.autECLPS.Refresh'."

I've spent about an hour looking through the IBM knowledge center on how to read a field and tried establishing different connections and this is what I think is the closest to solving my problem. I must be missing one key element. Here is my code which I paste into notepad:

```
[PCOMM SCRIPT HEADER]
LANGUAGE=VBSCRIPT
DESCRIPTION=PO_Price_Change
[PCOMM SCRIPT SOURCE]
OPTION EXPLICIT

Dim IBMItemNum
Dim counter

IBMItemNum = 1
counter = 0

autECLSession.SetConnectionByName(ThisSessionName)
UpdateAll_

'This method enters the PO and then calls FindItemNum to parse through the items
sub UpdateOnePO(PONum,ItemNum,Price)
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "4"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys PONum
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]" 'now within the PO
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]" 'now on first line
Call MatchItemNum(ItemNum,Price)
IBMItemNum = 1
counter = 0 'Reset counter and IBMItemNum for next PO
end sub

'This method parses through the PO to find ItemNum
sub MatchItemNum(ItemNum,Price)
Do While IBMItemNum <> 0
counter = counter + 1
If counter > 11 Then
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[PGDN]" 'page down since bottom of lines reached
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]" 'tab to return to first line of PO
counter = 0 'reset counter
End if
autECLSession.autECLPS.Refresh()
IBMItemNum = autECLSession.autECLPS.GetText()
If IBMItemNum = ItemNum Then 'If-Then statement once ItemNum is found
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys Price
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[field+]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "Y"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"
IBMItemNum = 0 'exit condition for loop
Else 'Tab five times to reach next line
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[tab]"
End if
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[F3]"
end sub

'This  method calls UpdateOnePO for all the POs, Item Numbers, and Prices entered into excel. This method will be produced by excel through VBA
sub UpdateAll_()
Call UpdateOnePO(55555,55555,55.55)
end sub
```

Comment: I get what you're trying to do, I think, but would you not be better writing (or getting someone else to write) an RPG (or indeed PHP, or Java, or whatever) program to run on the i and update the prices, loading the Excel spreadsheet into a temp table to provide the input? (Or, indeed, you could use a program running on the Windows client to achieve the same without needing to auto-navigate your green screen application.) I suspect it would be quicker in the end, especially if (as I assume) you will be doing this update more than once. (You would also be able to add suitable audit logging etc)

Comment: I have done this kind of "screen scripting" before. The advantage is that the input does through the same validation that hand typed data goes through and that any fields in any tables that the RPG program writes to get updated. This can be a data integrity and even auditing advantage over a raw SQL upload. The downside is that it is slower and harder to make reliable. I have found that you will [usually need code to handle timing issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33309939/3175562). That link can show you the concept of using the AutOIA.WaitForInputReady in VB.NET rather than VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

It gives you your answer right in the error message.  According to the documentation, autECLPS doesn't have a Refresh method. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQ5Y_5.9.0/com.ibm.pcomm.doc/books/html/host_access02.htm#ToC_1470

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the line

```
autECLSession.autECLPS.Refresh()
```

but it is the one that is causing you issues.  Might you be looking for something like this?

```
autECLPSObj.autECLFieldList.Refresh()
```