# What is best approach to write VBA script to Launch recorded macros on the AS400?

Tags: vba, ibm-midrange

I am new to connecting to the AS400 using Windows Client Access emulator. I have written VBA scripts in Excel to load data to the AS400. Could someone suggest how to launch a AS400 macro using VBA. I have tried "STRPCO" and "STRPCCMMD", and "StartMacro" without success. I can select recorded macros from the CL menu, but I want to program the same in VBA. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51826556/how-to-take-input-from-excel-and-use-that-value-to-run-a-macro-in-as400

Comment: My second job out of college was working on an AS/400 in the middle 80's. I can not believe they are still out there!

Comment: from excel you want to run a CL or RPG program on the IBM i?   Get the IBM i access client solutions ODBC driver installed.  Get the VBA code to use ADODB.Connection to connect to the IBM i.  With that connection, use the SQL CALL statement to call a CL or RPG program on the IBM i.