# Creating and Calling Arrays via Personal Communication

Tags: vba, vb.net, ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator

I am trying to call an Array in Personal Communication (iSeries etc)
I have a script that should

```
Open the query screen
Run query 1
Wait for query 1 to finish
Run query 2
```

etc

In any other VB situation, I would use

```
Dim qryArray() as string = {“salesrep1”, “salerep28”, “salepay34”, “prod_inv_1”}
```

But here it keeps telling me `Expected end of statement`

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong here?

Secondly I need to know how to call an Array as a `SendKeys`

```
'Open Query
    autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "2" 'Run
    autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys 'Query Name Goes Here
    autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[field+]" 'Next
    autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "techops" 'Library
    autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[field+]" 'To top
    autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]" 'Go to query
    autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf3]" 'Exit to run query
```

Comment: is this .net or vba?  `qryArray=array("one","two","three")` is the vba way

Comment: vba I believe. If I try this, it says `qryArray` is undefined

Comment: you still need to dimension the array, so `Dim a() As Variant  :  
a = Array("a", "b", "c")` for example.

Comment: Thanks. I worked it out. Do you know how to use SendKeys to send an Array Value within a Do:Loop?

Comment: `for each v in myarray:application.sendkeys(cstr(v)):next v`

Comment: It looks like I can't dimension the array as it will always say `Expected End of Statement`. So when I try and `SendKeys` it will tell me there is a `type mismatch`

Comment: The previous way will say expected end of statement??

Comment: I haven't tried your `for each` yet as I'm not sure how they operate. Can this be used inside a Do:Loop, until the Array has been completed? If so, what does `cstr` do? And instead of application: I would be using `autECLSession.autECLPS.`
Is that right?

Comment: Okay. I have that working by just removing the last `v` from `next`. But now it just prints out all my query names at once, rather than printing it out, running, waiting, going to the next one and printing out the second name

Comment: You need to pause between sending, paced by the terminal.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/33310031/3175562

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with help from Natha_Sav, here is the working answer:

```
For each v in qryArray
'Then we are opening the query, running it, closing it and waiting for the message to confirm
'snippet:
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "2" 'Run
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SetCursorPos 8, 26
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys(cstr(v)) 'send query name
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SetCursorPos 9, 28
'autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "salesrep1" 'This would be the equivalent
'then close the library etc 
'run the query
next
```