# How to unlock X SYSTEM PCOMM ibm as400 terminal from within VBA excel code? If not autECLOIA.InputInhibited = 0 Then

Tags: excel, vba, automation, screen-scraping, ibm-midrange

I'm running an excel automation macro to read IbM as400 terminal window data. My macro is running faster than the terminal window causing sometimes the autECLOIA console msg system to stop with a red X SYSTEM stop message.

I tried to include in my code the 
If not autECLOIA.InputInhibited = 0 Then
statement, but failed with error msg's. 
Could someone help me?

```
Option Explicit

'
'<------------- Definitions --------------------------------------------------------------------
'

'main sheet and connectivity declarations
Public DAT As Worksheet
Public CurrentRow As Long

Public autECLSession As Object
Public autECLPS As Object
Public autECLOIA As Object
Public autECLConnList As Object

'main declarations used by forms
Public CompanyID As String
Public Cancel As Boolean
Public Curr As String
Public Route1 As String, Route2 As String

'date variable definitions for entire programm
Public TodaysDate As Date
Public TodaysDateShort As String
Public TodaysDateAS As String
Public TodaysDateQuery As String
Public StartDate As Date
Public EndDate As Date
Public EndDateShort As String
Public EndDateAS As String
Public EndDateQuery As String
Public dateVariable As Date
Public TimeNow As String
Public CurrentDate As Date
Public DateTime As String
Public DateQ As String

'other declarations - minor
Public From As String
Public StartRowST As Byte
Public CountDep As Byte
Public EndRowST As Byte

Public myNewRangeSize As String



'
'<------------- Main subroutine ----------------------------------------------------------------
'
Sub Start()
    'definitions and for initialisation
        Set DAT = Worksheets("DATA")
        Load StartImport
        StartImport.Show
        If Cancel = True Then Exit Sub

    'Accordingly to currency the route changes
        If Curr = "PLN" Then
            Route1 = "SWITRE"
            Route2 = "TRESWI"
        Else
            Route1 = "KONTRE"
            Route2 = "TREKON"
        End If

    'data transfer functions
        'set and format dates
        StartEndFormatDates


        'start import
        If CompanyID = "TT" Then
            'code for importing TT-Line data kontinent to trelleborg
                CurrentDate = StartDate
                Do Until DateValue(CurrentDate) = DateValue(DateAdd("d", 1, EndDate))

                    EnterSailingTimetableCountOneDaysDepartures Route1, CurrentDate

                    'MsgBox "CurrentDate = " & CurrentDate & _
                    'vbCrLf & "StartRowST = " & StartRowST & _
                    'vbCrLf & "CountDep = " & CountDep & _
                    'vbCrLf & "EndRowST = " & EndRowST

                    If StartRowST = 0 And EndRowST = 0 Then
                        'do nothing
                    Else
                        ImportMainST Route1, CurrentDate
                    End If

                    'switching route

                    EnterSailingTimetableCountOneDaysDepartures Route2, CurrentDate

                    If StartRowST = 0 And EndRowST = 0 Then
                        'do nothing
                    Else
                        ImportMainST Route2, CurrentDate
                    End If

                    CurrentDate = DateAdd("d", 1, CurrentDate)
                Loop

        Else
            'enter here code for importing other data

        End If

        Dim myNewRangeSize As Long

        myNewRangeSize = DAT.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
        DAT.ListObjects("DataTable").Resize Range("$A$1:$Z$" & myNewRangeSize)

End Sub

'
'<------------- Main functions -----------------------------------------------------------------
'

'formats start and end dates to 3 formats = Human, AS400 and Query
Function StartEndFormatDates()
    'Work on todays date
    TodaysDate = Format(Now, "dd.mm.yyyy")
    TodaysDateShort = Format(TodaysDate, "dd.mm.yy")
    TodaysDateAS = Format(TodaysDate, "ddmmyy")

    Dim DateSplit() As String
    DateSplit() = Split(TodaysDate, ".")
    TodaysDateQuery = DateSplit(2) & "-" & DateSplit(1) & "-" & DateSplit(0)

    'Go to calendar to pick a date for outbound
    'AdvancedCalendar                   'checked
    'Check if any date chosen from calendar
    If EndDate < TodaysDate Then 'if user closes calendar without picking a date the program ends here
        'SendKeys2Extra "[pf3]"
        MsgBox ("You ended. Thank you.")
        Call ObjEndExtra
        Exit Function
    End If

    'EndDate = Format(dateVariable, "dd.mm.yyyy")
    EndDateShort = Format(EndDate, "dd.mm.yy")
    EndDateAS = Format(EndDate, "ddmmyy")

    DateSplit() = Split(EndDate, ".")
    EndDateQuery = DateSplit(2) & "-" & DateSplit(1) & "-" & DateSplit(0)
    'DispMsg (EndDate)

    'time now
    TimeNow = Format(Now, "hh:mm")
End Function

'enters ST in book window on given route and date --> counts first ST row and the number of departures
Function EnterSailingTimetableCountOneDaysDepartures(Rou As String, CheckDate As Date)
    'get into ST
    SendStr Left(Rou, 3) & Right(Rou, 3), 5, 9
    SendStr Format(CheckDate, "ddmmyy"), 5, 23
    Send "enter"
    '
        '<@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ here I would want something like this @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@:
'If not autECLOIA.InputInhibited = 0 Then
'   send "reset/ctrl"
'end if
'<=================================== but it doesn't work - generating object errors

    'define variables
    StartRowST = 0
    CountDep = 0
    EndRowST = 0
    DateTime = ""
    Dim i As Byte, stopif As Boolean
    stopif = False

    'start loop through ST screen to compare dates and time
    For i = 1 To 18
        autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
        '
            '

        FromAS 5 + i, 17, 8
        'MsgBox "In search for last row:" & _
        'vbCrLf & "From = " & CDate(Format(From, "dd.mm.yyyy")) & _
        'vbCrLf & "Checkdate+1 day = " & CDate(DateAdd("d", 1, CheckDate))
        Dim Spl() As String
        Spl() = Split(From, ".")
        From = Spl(0) & "." & Spl(1) & ".20" & Spl(2)

        If CDate(From) = CDate(DateAdd("d", 1, CheckDate)) Then
            'counts where is last Row in ST
            If EndRowST > 0 Then
                EndRowST = EndRowST - 1
                Exit For
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Else
            'read and set DateTime for determininig first row in ST
            'FromAS 5 + i, 17, 8
            DateTime = Format(From, "dd.mm.yyyy")
            FromAS 5 + i, 32, 5
            DateTime = DateTime & " " & Replace(From, ".", ":")
            'MsgBox "DateTime = " & DateTime & _
            'vbCrLf & "CheckDate = " & CheckDate & _
            'vbCrLf & "Todaysdate+TimeNow = " & TodaysDate & " " & TimeNow

            'check if DateTime read from ST bigger then Now - if so then counting first row and departures
            If (CDate(DateTime) > CDate(TodaysDate & " " & TimeNow)) And StartRowST = 0 Then
                StartRowST = 5 + i
                CountDep = CountDep + 1
                EndRowST = StartRowST
            ElseIf (CDate(DateTime) < CDate(TodaysDate & " " & TimeNow)) And StartRowST = 0 Then
                stopif = True
            ElseIf (CDate(DateTime) > CDate(TodaysDate & " " & TimeNow)) And StartRowST > 0 Then
                CountDep = CountDep + 1
            End If

            If stopif = False Then
                EndRowST = EndRowST + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    'exits ST details to first ST screen to be ready for checking next date
    Send "pf3"
End Function

Function ImportMainST(Rou As String, CheckDate As Date)
    'get into ST
    SendStr Left(Rou, 3) & Right(Rou, 3), 5, 9
    SendStr Format(CheckDate, "ddmmyy"), 5, 23
    Send "enter"
    '
        '


    Dim i As Byte, j As Integer, x As Integer, y As Byte, startI As Integer

    Dim Dep As String, Arr As String, WeekD As String, DepTime As String, Ship As String, _
    WL As String, Canc As String, Price As String, BookedPax As String, Deck As String, _
    FreePAX As String, FreeLPpax As String, MIS1 As Integer, MIS10 As Integer, _
    MIS20 As Integer, MIS30 As Integer  ', BPax As Integer

    Dim Typ(19) As String
    Dim BNAmo(19) As String 'booked normal cabins - type and amount
    Dim KLAmo(19) As String 'booked komf/lux cabins sum
    Dim FNAmo(19) As String 'free normal cabins sum
    Dim FKLAmo(19) As String 'free komf/lux cabins sum
    Dim FLPAmo(19) As String 'free low price cabins sum


    Dim BNSum As Integer 'booked normal cabins sum
    Dim KLSum As Integer 'booked komf/lux cabins sum
    Dim FNSum As Integer 'free normal cabins sum
    Dim FKLSum As Integer 'free komf/lux cabins sum
    Dim FLPSum As Integer 'free low price cabins sum

    startI = 1
    'importing main ST screen
    For i = StartRowST To EndRowST
        CurrentRow = DAT.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        '<-------- Sail.Time: X -------->
        If startI = 1 Then
            'do nothing
        Else
            SendStr "X", 25, 31
            Send "enter"
            '
                '


        End If

        'A date of entry - todaysdate
        DAT.Range("A" & CurrentRow) = TodaysDate

        'B compnay - CompanyComboBox
        DAT.Range("B" & CurrentRow) = CompanyID

        'C Dep
        FromAS i, 6, 9
        Dep = Left(From, 3)
        DAT.Range("C" & CurrentRow) = Dep

        'D Arr
        Arr = Right(From, 3)
        DAT.Range("D" & CurrentRow) = Arr

        'E Dep date - CurrentDate
        DAT.Range("E" & CurrentRow) = CurrentDate

        'F Weekday
        'FromAS i, 27, 2
        'WeekD = From
        DAT.Range("F" & CurrentRow) = Weekday(CurrentDate)

        'G Time
        FromAS i, 32, 5
        DepTime = Replace(From, ".", ":")
        DAT.Range("G" & CurrentRow) = DepTime

        'Z Dep timeframe
        If DepTime >= TimeValue("05:00:00") And DepTime < TimeValue("13:00:00") Then
            DAT.Range("Z" & CurrentRow) = "Morning"
        ElseIf DepTime >= TimeValue("13:00:00") And DepTime < TimeValue("19:00:00") Then
            DAT.Range("Z" & CurrentRow) = "Afternoon"
        ElseIf DepTime >= TimeValue("19:00:00") And DepTime < TimeValue("00:00:00") Then
            DAT.Range("Z" & CurrentRow) = "Evening"
        ElseIf DepTime >= TimeValue("00:00:00") And DepTime < TimeValue("05:00:00") Then
            DAT.Range("Z" & CurrentRow) = "Night"
        End If

        'H Ship
        FromAS i, 39, 2
        Ship = From
        DAT.Range("H" & CurrentRow) = Ship

        'I WL
        FromAS i, 59, 3
        If Trim(From) <> "" Then WL = From
        DAT.Range("I" & CurrentRow) = WL

        'J Canc
        FromAS i, 72, 4
        If Trim(From) <> "" Then Canc = From
        DAT.Range("J" & CurrentRow) = From

        If DAT.Range("J" & CurrentRow) <> "CANC" Then
            'K - Price
            FromAS i, 85, 4
            Price = Trim(From)
            DAT.Range("K" & CurrentRow) = Price

            'L - Currency from CurrencyComboBox
            DAT.Range("L" & CurrentRow) = Curr


            '<-------- Cabin-Av: B -------->
            SendStr "B", 25, 43
            Send "enter"
            autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
            '
                '


            'M booked PAX
            FromAS i, 27, 3
            If IsNumeric(Trim(From)) = True Then
                BookedPax = Trim(From)
            Else
                BookedPax = 0
            End If
            DAT.Range("M" & CurrentRow) = BookedPax

            'T - Booked Cab
            BNSum = 0
            x = 0
            For j = 0 To 19
                FromAS 5, 32 + x, 4
                Typ(j) = Trim(From)
                FromAS i, 32 + x, 4
                BNAmo(j) = Trim(From)

                If IsNumeric(Trim(BNAmo(j))) = True Then
                'MsgBox "Right(Trim(Typ(j)), 1) = " & Right(Trim(Typ(j)), 1) & vbCrLf & "Trim(Typ(j) = " & Trim(Typ(j))
                    If (Right(Trim(Typ(j)), 1) <> "K" Or Right(Trim(Typ(j)), 1) <> "L") And (Trim(Typ(j)) <> "LOUN" Or Trim(Typ(j)) <> "PULL") Then
                        BNSum = BNSum + CInt(BNAmo(j))
                    End If
                End If

                x = x + 5
                'MsgBox Typ(j) & " = " & BNAmo(j)
            Next j
            DAT.Range("T" & CurrentRow) = BNSum


            'U - Booked K/L Cab
            KLSum = 0
            x = 0
            For j = 0 To 19
                FromAS i, 32 + x, 4
                KLAmo(j) = Trim(From)

                If IsNumeric(Trim(KLAmo(j))) = True Then
                    If (Right(Trim(Typ(j)), 1) = "K" Or Right(Trim(Typ(j)), 1) = "L") And (Trim(Typ(j)) <> "PULL" Or Trim(Typ(j)) <> "LOUN") Then
                        KLSum = KLSum + CInt(KLAmo(j))
                    End If
                End If


                x = x + 5
                'MsgBox Typ(j) & " = " & KLAmo(j)
            Next j
            DAT.Range("U" & CurrentRow) = KLSum




            '<-------- Cabin-Av: X -------->
            SendStr "X", 25, 43
            Send "enter"
            autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
            '
                '


            'R free PAX
            FromAS i, 27, 3
            If IsNumeric(Trim(From)) = True Then
                FreePAX = Trim(From)
            Else
                FreePAX = 0
            End If
            DAT.Range("R" & CurrentRow) = FreePAX

            'V - Free Cabins
            FNSum = 0
            x = 0
            For j = 0 To 19
                FromAS 5, 32 + x, 4
                Typ(j) = Trim(From)
                FromAS i, 32 + x, 4
                FNAmo(j) = Trim(From)

                If IsNumeric(Trim(FNAmo(j))) = True Then
                    If (Right(Trim(Typ(j)), 1) <> "K" Or Right(Trim(Typ(j)), 1) <> "L" Or Trim(Typ(j)) <> "SU4") And (Trim(Typ(j)) <> "LOUN" Or Trim(Typ(j)) <> "PULL") Then
                        FNSum = FNSum + CInt(FNAmo(j))
                    End If
                End If


                x = x + 5
                'MsgBox Typ(j) & " = " & FNAmo(j)
            Next j
            DAT.Range("V" & CurrentRow) = FNSum

            'W - Free K/L Cab
            FKLSum = 0
            x = 0
            For j = 0 To 19
                FromAS i, 32 + x, 4
                FKLAmo(j) = Trim(From)

                If IsNumeric(Trim(FKLAmo(j))) = True Then
                    If (Right(Trim(Typ(j)), 1) = "K" Or Right(Trim(Typ(j)), 1) = "L" Or Trim(Typ(j)) = "SU4") And (Trim(Typ(j)) <> "PULL" Or Trim(Typ(j)) <> "LOUN") Then
                        FKLSum = FKLSum + CInt(FKLAmo(j))
                    End If
                End If

                x = x + 5
                'MsgBox Typ(j) & " = " & FKLAmo(j)
            Next j
            DAT.Range("W" & CurrentRow) = FKLSum

            '<-------- Cabin-Av: L -------->
            SendStr "L", 25, 43
            Send "enter"
            autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
            '
                '


            'S - Free LP PAX
            FromAS i, 27, 3
            If IsNumeric(Trim(From)) = True Then
                FreeLPpax = Trim(From)
            Else
                FreeLPpax = 0
            End If
            DAT.Range("S" & CurrentRow) = FreeLPpax

            'X - Free LP Cab
            FLPSum = 0
            x = 0
            For j = 0 To 19
                FromAS 4, 32 + x, 4
                Typ(j) = Trim(From)
                FromAS i, 32 + x, 4
                FLPAmo(j) = Trim(From)

                If IsNumeric(Trim(FLPAmo(j))) = True Then
                    If Trim(Typ(j)) <> "LOUN" Or Trim(Typ(j)) <> "PULL" Then
                        FLPSum = FLPSum + CInt(FLPAmo(j))
                    End If
                End If

                x = x + 5
                'MsgBox Typ(j) & " = " & FLPAmo(j)
            Next j
            DAT.Range("X" & CurrentRow) = FLPSum


            '<--------Deck-Av: X -------->
            SendStr "X", 25, 54
            Send "Enter"
            autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
            '
                '


            'Y Free Deck
            FromAS i, 32, 3
            Deck = Trim(From)
            DAT.Range("Y" & CurrentRow) = Deck

            '<-------- Query -------->

            Send "pf3"
            Send "pf3"
            Send "pf3"
            autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
            '
                '


            SendStr "6", 20, 7
            Send "enter"
            autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
            '
                '


            SendStr "2", 5, 26
            SendStr "KOORDINAT", 9, 28
            Send "enter"
            autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
            '
                '


            Send "pf4"
            SendStr "2A_01GREG", 11, 3
            Send "enter"
            autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
            '
                '


            SendStr "1", 13, 3
            Send "enter"
            autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
            '
                '


            Dim SplQ() As String
            SplQ() = Split(CheckDate, ".")
            DateQ = SplQ(2) & "-" & SplQ(1) & "-" & SplQ(0)

            SendStr DateQ, 7, 36
            SendStr Dep, 8, 36
            SendStr Arr, 9, 36
            SendStr DepTime, 10, 36

            '
                '

            autECLSession.autECLPS.SetCursorPos 12, 35
            autECLSession.autECLPS.SetCursorPos 12, 35
            autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
            SendStr "'01'                          ", 12, 35
            '
                '


            autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
            Send "pf5"
            autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
            '
                '


            'N Booked MIS 1
            FromAS 6, 7, 1
            If IsNumeric(From) Then
                FromAS 7, 41, 3
                If Trim(From) <> "" Then
                    MIS1 = Trim(From)
                Else
                    MIS1 = 0
                End If
            Else
                MIS1 = 0
            End If
            DAT.Range("N" & CurrentRow) = MIS1
            '
                '


            Send "pf3"
            autECLSession.autECLPS.SetCursorPos 12, 35
            autECLSession.autECLPS.SetCursorPos 12, 35
            '
                '

            autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
            SendStr "'10'                          ", 12, 35
            Send "pf5"
            autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
            '
                '


            'O MIS 10
            FromAS 6, 7, 1
            If IsNumeric(From) Then
                FromAS 7, 41, 3
                If Trim(From) <> "" Then
                    MIS10 = Trim(From)
                Else
                    MIS10 = 0
                End If
            Else
                MIS10 = 0
            End If
            DAT.Range("O" & CurrentRow) = MIS10
            '
                '


            Send "pf3"
            autECLSession.autECLPS.SetCursorPos 12, 35
            autECLSession.autECLPS.SetCursorPos 12, 35
            '
                '

            autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
            SendStr "'20'                          ", 12, 35
            Send "pf5"
            autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
            '
                '


            'P MIS 20
            FromAS 6, 7, 1
            If IsNumeric(From) Then
                FromAS 7, 41, 3
                If Trim(From) <> "" Then
                    MIS20 = Trim(From)
                Else
                    MIS20 = 0
                End If
            Else
                MIS20 = 0
            End If
            DAT.Range("P" & CurrentRow) = MIS20

            Send "pf3"

            autECLSession.autECLPS.SetCursorPos 12, 35
            autECLSession.autECLPS.SetCursorPos 12, 35
            '
                '

            autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
            SendStr "'30'                          ", 12, 35
            Send "pf5"
            autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
            '
                '


            'Q MIS 30
            FromAS 6, 7, 1
            If IsNumeric(From) Then
                FromAS 7, 41, 3
                If Trim(From) <> "" Then
                    MIS30 = Trim(From)
                Else
                    MIS30 = 0
                End If
            Else
                MIS30 = 0
            End If
            DAT.Range("Q" & CurrentRow) = MIS30
            '
                '


            autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
            Send "pf12"
            Send "pf3"
            autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady (750)
            '
                '


            autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
            SendStr "N", 5, 29
            Send "enter"
            '
                '


                autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady

                Send "pf3"
                autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
                '
                    '


                SendStr "1", 20, 7
                Send "enter"
                '
                    '

                autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
                SendStr "13", 20, 7
                Send "enter"
                '
                    '

                autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady

            CheckResource
            If CheckResource = True Then
                SendStr Left(Rou, 3) & Right(Rou, 3), 5, 9
                SendStr Format(CheckDate, "ddmmyy"), 5, 23
                Send "enter"
            Else
                MsgBox "Error. Not in ST. Unlock book window, and go to ST. If macro starts, leave it.", vbOKOnly, "Error"                
            End If

        End If

        '
            '

        startI = startI + 1
    Next i

    'exits ST details to first ST screen to be ready for checking next date
    Send "pf3"
End Function



'<------------------------------- START, STOP FUNCTIONS -------------------------------------
'
' Set up fields need to link to 5250 session - Copy this block into any new Screen Scrapper macro as is
'
Sub ObjGetExtra()
    DAT.Unprotect ("Coordination")
    'DAT.Select
    Set autECLSession = CreateObject("pcomm.auteclsession")
    Set autECLPS = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLPS")
    Set autECLOIA = CreateObject("Pcomm.autecloia")
    'Set autECLConnList = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLConnList")
End Sub

Sub ObjEndExtra()
    Set autECLSession = Nothing
    Set autECLPS = Nothing
    Set autECLOIA = Nothing
    'Set autECLConnList = Nothing
    DAT.Protect ("Coordination")
End Sub


'<------------------------------ FUNCTIONS FOR AS400 PROCESSING --------------------------------

'
' Put the value on the 5250 screen at the position specified
'
Function SendStr(ByVal Data As String, ByVal Row As Long, ByVal Col As Long)
    autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
    autECLSession.autECLPS.SetCursorPos Row, Col
    autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys Data, Row, Col
End Function

'
' Read a string from the 5250 screen strarting at the position specified
'
Function FromAS(ByVal Row As Long, ByVal Col As Long, ByVal Lenght As Long) As String
    autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
    From = autECLSession.autECLPS.GetText(Row, Col, Lenght)
End Function

'
' Sent special keys to the session (function keys, enter, etc)
'
Function Send(Key As String)
 autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
 autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[" & Key & "]"
End Function

' Check if in Sailing Timetable
Function CheckResource() As Boolean
    FromAS 2, 20, 7
    '
        '

    If Trim(From) = "SAILING" Then
        FromAS 4, 11, 5
        '
            '
        '
        If Trim(From) = "Route" Then
            'do nothing
            CheckResource = True
        Else
            FromAS 4, 2, 3
            '
                '

            If Trim(From) = "Seq" Then
                Send "pf3"
                CheckResource = True
            End If
        End If
    Else
        CheckResource = False
    End If

End Function
```

```
'the form starting the comm session is here
'StartImport form code
'

Public SessionString As String
'Public handleConn As Byte

Private Sub RunButton_Click()
    If CompanyComboBox <> "select" Then
        If CompanyComboBox = "TT" And CurrencyComboBox <> "select" Then
            If SessionString <> "" Then
            'proper start sequence
                Call ObjGetExtra
                autECLSession.SetConnectionByname (SessionString)
                autECLPS.SetConnectionByname (SessionString)
                'autECLConnList.Refresh
                autECLOIA.SetConnectionByname (SessionString)
                If autECLSession.commstarted = False Then
                    MsgBox "There does not appear to be a session '" & SessionString & "'. Please Check and try again.", vbOKOnly, "Error"
                    Call ObjEndExtra
                End If

                Call CheckResource
                If CheckResource = True Then
                    CompanyID = CompanyComboBox
                    Curr = CurrencyComboBox
                    StartDate = FromDateF
                    EndDate = ToDateF
                    Unload Me
                Else
                    MsgBox "You are not in ST, please start ST in choosen session and start again.", vbOKOnly, "Error"
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox "No Session button choosen.", vbOKOnly, "Error"
            End If
        ElseIf CompanyComboBox <> "TT" Then
            CompanyID = CompanyComboBox
            CurrencyComboBox = "EUR"
            StartDate = FromDateF
            EndDate = ToDateF
            Unload Me
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing selected to be done", vbOKOnly, "Error"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Session1_Click()
    If Session1 = True Then
        SessionString = "A"
        'handleConn = 1
        Session2 = False
        Session3 = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Session2_Click()
    If Session2 = True Then
        SessionString = "B"
        'handleConn = 2
        Session1 = False
        Session3 = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Session3_Click()
    If Session3 = True Then
        SessionString = "C"
        'handleConn = 3
        Session1 = False
        Session2 = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CompanyComboBox_Change()
    If CompanyComboBox = "TT" Then CurrencyComboBox.value = "select"
End Sub

Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    UserForm_QueryClose 0, 0
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'Company choice
    With Me.CompanyComboBox
        .AddItem "TT"
        'rest deleted
    End With

    'Currency choice
    With Me.CurrencyComboBox
        .AddItem "EUR"
        'rest deleted
    End With


End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = 0 Then
        Call ObjEndExtra
        Cancel = True
        Unload Me
        MsgBox "You ended. Thank you.", vbOKOnly, "Exit"
        End
    End If
End Sub
```

everywhere where you see in two lines: '

there should be some error handling like (above from code):
If not autECLOIA.InputInhibited = 0 Then
   send "reset/ctrl"
end if

but it doesn't work - generating object errors

Answer (score 0):

The pace of your macro must be throttled by the speed of the terminal screen.  I have been using a solution shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33310031/3175562 to make the Automation calls wait for when the terminal is ready.