# VBA Macro for use AS400

Tags: excel, vba, ibm-midrange

I want to automate AS400 through a VBA code.

I would make a simple macro that make access to AS400 and insert some text in a field.

It is possible?

I search on internet and i understand that exist a PCOMM properties that allow to command AS400 from VBA Macro. It's right?

Thank's for your support!

Comment: @SMeaden Indeed it is.  I believe the poster's intent is to use some communication functionality external to Excel which provides glue between running automated tasks on an AS400 machine and an interface exposed in an Excel workbook.  But really need more specifics from OP.

Comment: This maybe of use https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/477817/pcomm-for-as400-automation-with-excel/

Comment: Also this, https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24956712/AS400-PCOMM-Read-Write-Issue-in-VBA.html

Comment: Here is another IBM webpage https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQ5Y_5.9.0/com.ibm.pcomm.doc/books/html/host_access08.htm

Comment: I've used sendkeys in the past with some success in JDE on AS400

Comment: This is the kind of thing that I have done on a large scale, making a .NET dll with one class associated with each display file screen on the IBM. The class properties correlate with screen fields. In Excel, I have simple "updating worksheets" where you can press a button and update all the data in the column. VBA code calls my .dll which provides the actual update mechanism. Some people would scoff at doing massive data updates through the emulator interface, but I like the fact that unlike SQL updates, the data must run through the display's RPG for validation with errors returned to Excel.

Comment: Related:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/33309939/3175562